# Wordpress - How to create link to a data-filter element?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

A page of my WordPress site use an On page filter menu which user can click on items to filter posts type below. Is there a way to create a link to every filter menu item which user can access directly to them from outside of this page?  Please see the html code below:

```
<ul class="filter js-filter">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#" data-filter=".building">Building </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#" data-filter=".villa">Villa </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#" data-filter=".interior">Interior </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#" data-filter=".exterior">Exterior </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to use jQuery's [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to simulate a click on the appropriate element based on a URL Fragment (hash in the URL)

Links:

```
<a href="https://example.com/filter-page#*">Filter All</a>
<a href="https://example.com/filter-page#.building">Filter Buildings</a>
```

JavaScript on your filter page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var currentFilter = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    $('.js-filter [data-filter="'+ currentFilter +'"]').trigger('click');
});
```