# link to a page with data filter preselected

Tags: jquery, button, filter, hyperlink, click

I am not a great coder and I've never asked a question on this site, so bear with me.

I have a page that has a menu that filters data by using button clicks.

This is the page:  https://troubletest1.jcink.net/index.php?act=Pages&kid=char2

What I want is to be able to create a link to the page with a one (or more) of the filters already preselected for you.

For example one of the filters is by the author of the character.  In this case, we'll use me, Jennz.

```
<div class="button2-group" data-filter-group="ooc">
<myh1>Who Plays Who</myh1>
<button2 class="button2 is-checked" data-filter="">all</button2>
<button2 class="button2" data-filter=".lexi">Lexi - Staff</button2>
<button2 class="button2" data-filter=".jennz">Jennz - Staff</button2>
```

I tried some things I thought were similar and might work but they didn't work for me.

Like this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49883277/10554102

The bottom line is I would like to be able to create a link to that page that shows just those characters that are played by a particular author and not the whole grid of characters.

I would appreciate any help on this.  Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Adding in the codes that are being used:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({


itemSelector: '.grid-item'
 });

 // store filter for each group
 var filters = {};

 $('.filters').on( 'click', '.button2', function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   // get group key
   var $button2Group = $this.parents('.button2-group');
   var filterGroup = $button2Group.attr('data-filter-group');
   // set filter for group
   filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
   // combine filters
   var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
   // set filter for Isotope
   $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
 });

 // change is-checked class on button2s
 $('.button2-group').each( function( i, button2Group ) {
   var $button2Group = $( button2Group );
   $button2Group.on( 'click', 'button2', function() {
     $button2Group.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
     $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
   });
 });

});

// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
 var value = '';
 for ( var prop in obj ) {
   value += obj[ prop ];
 }
 return value;
}
```

EDIT 2:

After trying a code suggested by James Hull, I ran into another problem.

This is how I placed the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
 // init Isotope
 var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
   itemSelector: '.grid-item'
 });


// Sample code using jQuery trigger
$(function(){
    var paramsString = "ooc=jennz&ooc=lexi"; // example search url
    // IE does not support URLSearchParams().
    // So you'll need to find another way to get the params if IE support needed
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
    // Iterate the search parameters.
    for (var p of searchParams) {
        // trigger appropriate filters
        $('[data-filter-group="' + p[0]  + '"').find('[data-filter=".' + p[1] + '"]').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

This is how I'm doing the links:
https://troubletest1.jcink.net/index.php?act=Pages&kid=char2#.lexi

And right now, the page will not reset at all unless I manually go in and select the "all" filter button.   Normally, it would default back to "all" on a page refresh and that's not doing it now.  Anytime I go to the page, even with a link that doesn't have the #.lexi or any parameter it's still selecting her specific characters only.

As I said, I'm a novice at this stuff, so I'm not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: You could pass the parameters as query string parameters in your url and then grab those from the url when the page loads and then use that to filter down the page. This article may help (https://www.arungudelli.com/tutorial/javascript/get-query-string-parameter-values-from-url-using-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RyanWilson  I looked over that article.  I get passing the parameters but I don't know how to get it to trigger the filter.  In this case, triggering the button click I guess is what needs to happen.

Comment: Are the filter button click events attached to the buttons using jQuery?

Comment: @JamesHull    I believe so.  I have added the relevant code to the original post.  Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `trigger()` function should be sufficient. If you can grab query string parameters as you mention above in the comments, you should be able to use name/value pairs to trigger the appropriate buttons.
The 'name' being the filter group and the 'value' being the specific filter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item'
    });

    // store filter for each group
    var filters = {`enter code here`};

    $('.filters').on( 'click', '.button2', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // get group key
        var $button2Group = $this.parents('.button2-group');
        var filterGroup = $button2Group.attr('data-filter-group');
        // set filter for group
        filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
        // combine filters
        var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
        // set filter for Isotope
        $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });


    // change is-checked class on button2s
    $('.button2-group').each( function( i, button2Group ) {
       var $button2Group = $( button2Group );
       $button2Group.on( 'click', 'button2', function() {
         $button2Group.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
         $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
      });
    });

    // IE does not support URLSearchParams().
    // So you'll need to find another way to get the params if IE support needed
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    // Iterate the search parameters.
    for (var p of searchParams) {
        // trigger appropriate filters
        $('[data-filter-group="' + p[0]  + '"').find('[data-filter="' + p[1] + '"]').trigger('click');
    }

});

// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
 var value = '';
 for ( var prop in obj ) {
   value += obj[ prop ];
 }
 return value;
}
```

Comment: Be sure the code triggering the buttons will need to be defined in the on document ready function after the click events are attached to the buttons.

Comment: Thank you, that did work for me and suits my purposes at the moment.  However, would there be a way to have that paramsString variable be able to be more dynamic so that you don't have to hard code something in there like the ooc=jennz?

Comment: Also, found an issue.   It's not reseting the page after selecting one.   I'll add the code to my OP to show how I did it.  But, when I use the link to go to the page for one person it shows their characters just fine.   If I then try to go to the page using another link for another person, it still shows person 1's characters, not person 2's.

Comment: The hard coded string was just an example. You'll need to grab the actual query string from the live URL using `window.location.search`.
You'll need to leave in the code that assigns jQuery click events onto the buttons, removing them could be why the filter may not be working now. I've updated my code answer to include everything from your code and mine.

Comment: So now you should be able to use links like the previous example text https://troubletest1.jcink.net/index.php?act=Pages&kid=char2&group=may1&ooc=.jennz

Comment: Thanks again for your help.   I'm still struggling with this.   Adding in that new bit breaks the rest of the code.  The grid doesn't properly set up (they don't spread out horizontally, each grid item stacks vertically)  and the filters don't work at all.     I am so over my head with this.  By the way, this is a code that I am adapting, I did not create the original filter/grid code.